# mouse click event on Tab header in Tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, click, mouseevent, tabcontrol

I have my `TabControl` made in WPF with C#.  But I display the window like a bar by using window position.  I mean while displaying only tabheader will be display.  My tab header are in the left side.  When I press the tabheader the window width will increse to fit the tab items content.

So I want the click event of tab headers in tabcontrol.  How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Set the window to auto size to it's content using the Window property: `SizeToContent`
2. Use the `TabControl` event: `SelectionChanged`